# Preserve cookies / localStorage session across tests in Cypress

Tags: cookies, token, cypress

I want to save/persist/preserve a cookie or localStorage token that is set by a **cy.request()**, so that I don't have to use a custom command to login on every test. This should work for tokens like **jwt** (json web tokens) that are stored in the client's localStorage.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

From the Cypress [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq#How-do-I-preserve-cookies--localStorage-in-between-my-tests)

**For persisting cookies**: By default, Cypress automatically clears all cookies before each test to prevent state from building up.

You can configure specific cookies to be preserved across tests using the Cypress.Cookies api:

```
// now any cookie with the name 'session_id' will
// not be cleared before each test runs
Cypress.Cookies.defaults({
  preserve: "session_id"
})
```

**NOTE**: Before Cypress v5.0 the configuration key is "whitelist", not "preserve".

**For persisting localStorage**: It's not built in ATM, but you can achieve it manually right now because the method thats clear local storage is publicly exposed as Cypress.LocalStorage.clear.

You can backup this method and override it based on the keys sent in.

```
const clear = Cypress.LocalStorage.clear

Cypress.LocalStorage.clear = function (keys, ls, rs) {
  // do something with the keys here
  if (keys) {
    return clear.apply(this, arguments)
  }

}
```

Comment: Note: For cookies, this now seems to be `preserve` instead of `whitelist`

Comment: I'm sorry newbie here: so where would I include this method? in a command.js file? and how would I use it to say, add a specific key? thank you

Comment: @Citronex as for Cypress 10.8.0, put this method in [support/e2e.js](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests#Support-file)

Comment: this will not work with Cypress 13

Answer (score 58):

To update this thread, there is already a better solution available for preserving cookies (by @bkucera); but now there is a workaround available now to save and restore local storage between the tests (in case needed). I recently faced this issue; and found this solution working.

This solution is by using helper commands and consuming them inside the tests,

Inside - `cypress/support/<some_command>.js`

```
let LOCAL_STORAGE_MEMORY = {};

Cypress.Commands.add("saveLocalStorage", () => {
  Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(key => {
    LOCAL_STORAGE_MEMORY[key] = localStorage[key];
  });
});

Cypress.Commands.add("restoreLocalStorage", () => {
  Object.keys(LOCAL_STORAGE_MEMORY).forEach(key => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, LOCAL_STORAGE_MEMORY[key]);
  });
});
```

Then in test,

```
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.restoreLocalStorage();
});

afterEach(() => {
  cy.saveLocalStorage();
});
```

Reference: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/461#issuecomment-392070888

Comment: I did exactly this but it doesn't work for me :( I see the keys disappear after every test

Comment: Worked! For TypeScript use this: ```let LOCAL_STORAGE_MEMORY: { [key: string]: string; } = {};```

Answer (score 11):

You can add your own login command to Cypress, and use the [cypress-localstorage-commands](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-localstorage-commands) package to persist localStorage between tests.

In `support/commands`:

```js
import "cypress-localstorage-commands";

Cypress.Commands.add('loginAs', (UserEmail, UserPwd) => {
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: "/loginWithToken",
    body: {
      user: {
        email: UserEmail,
        password: UserPwd,
      }
    }
  })
    .its('body')
    .then((body) => {
      cy.setLocalStorage("accessToken", body.accessToken);
      cy.setLocalStorage("refreshToken", body.refreshToken);
    });
});
```

Inside your tests:

```js
describe("when user FOO is logged in", ()=> {
  before(() => {
    cy.loginAs("foo@foo.com", "fooPassword");
    cy.saveLocalStorage();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit("/your-private-page");
    cy.restoreLocalStorage();
  });

  it('should exist accessToken in localStorage', () => {
    cy.getLocalStorage("accessToken").should("exist");
  });

  it('should exist refreshToken in localStorage', () => {
    cy.getLocalStorage("refreshToken").should("exist");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure about local storage, but for cookies, I ended up doing the following to store all cookies between tests **once**.

```js
beforeEach(function () {
  cy.getCookies().then(cookies => {
    const namesOfCookies = cookies.map(c => c.name)
    Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce(...namesOfCookies)
  })
})
```

According to the documentation, `Cypress.Cookies.defaults` will maintain the changes for every test run after that. In my opinion, this is not ideal as this increases test suite coupling.

I added a more robust response in this Cypress issue: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/959#issuecomment-828077512

I know this is an old question but wanted to share my solution either way in case someone needs it.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution that worked for me:

```
 Cypress.LocalStorage.clear = function (keys, ls, rs) {
    return;
```

```
 before(() => {
    LocalStorage.clear();
    Login();
  })
```

Control of cookie clearing is supported by Cypress: https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/cookies.html

Comment: Can you please explain how this solution solves the issue? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: with each spec having a describe() containing a sequence of tests, with a single login at the start. Each test is in an it(), and we want to preserve both DOM and localStorage between the it()s as we use JWT login.

Comment: Please add that to your answer.

Comment: This is only a partial answer, your function is missing quite a bit of info and isn't complete. Maybe update to show the entire process.

Answer (score 1):

For keeping a google token cookie, there is a library called 
 **cypress-social-login**. 
 It seems to have other OAuth providers as a milestone. 
It's recommended by the cypress team and can be found on the cypress plugin page.

https://github.com/lirantal/cypress-social-logins

> This Cypress library makes it possible to perform third-party logins
>   (think oauth) for services such as GitHub, Google or Facebook.
>
> It does so by delegating the login process to a puppeteer flow that
>   performs the login and returns the cookies for the application under
>   test so they can be set by the calling Cypress flow for the duration
>   of the test.

Answer (score 1):

2023 Updated on Cypress v12 or more:

Since Cypress Version 12 you can use the new [cy.session()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session)

it cache and restore cookies, localStorage, and sessionStorage (i.e. session data) in order to recreate a consistent browser context between tests.

Here's how to use it

```javascript
// Caching session when logging in via page visit
cy.session(name, () => {
  cy.visit('/login')
  cy.get('[data-test=name]').type(name)
  cy.get('[data-test=password]').type('s3cr3t')
  cy.get('form').contains('Log In').click()
  cy.url().should('contain', '/login-successful')
})
```

Comment: I dont understand how you restore that session, for example in another test in the same spec file...

Comment: yes, you can see it as well in the documentation link i added above in my answer
"Cache and restore cookies, localStorage, and sessionStorage (i.e. session data) in order to recreate a consistent browser context between tests

Comment: Session won't work if your site must go to a secondary origin, back, and then back again. This will cause session to fail to properly setup a session. This can happen with Azure. I've yet to find a work around.

Answer (score 1):

Try this is working in my case

```html
// Save session data
let savedCookies;
let savedLocalStorage;
let savedSessionStorage;

before(() => {
  // Save session data
  cy.visit('https://example.com/login'); // Visit the login page

  // Log in and save session data
  cy.get('#username').type('your_username');
  cy.get('#password').type('your_password');
  cy.get('#login-button').click();

  // Save cookies
  cy.getCookies().then((cookies) => {
    savedCookies = cookies;
  });

  // Save localStorage
  savedLocalStorage = window.localStorage;

  // Save sessionStorage
  savedSessionStorage = window.sessionStorage;
});

// Restore session data
beforeEach(() => {
  // Restore cookies
  cy.clearCookies();
  savedCookies.forEach((cookie) => {
    cy.setCookie(cookie.name, cookie.value, {
      domain: cookie.domain,
      path: cookie.path,
      secure: cookie.secure,
      httpOnly: cookie.httpOnly,
      expiry: cookie.expires,
    });
  });

  // Restore localStorage
  Object.keys(savedLocalStorage).forEach((key) => {
    window.localStorage.setItem(key, savedLocalStorage.getItem(key));
  });

  // Restore sessionStorage
  Object.keys(savedSessionStorage).forEach((key) => {
    window.sessionStorage.setItem(key, savedSessionStorage.getItem(key));
  });
});

// Your Cypress test code
describe('My tests', () => {
  it('Test 1', () => {
    // The user is already logged in due to the before() hook

    // Your test assertions
  });

  it('Test 2', () => {
    // The user is still logged in due to the before() hook

    // Your test assertions
  });

  // More tests...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see suggestions to use whitelist. But it does not seem to work during `cypress run`.
Tried below methods in before() and beforeEach() respectively:

```
Cypress.Cookies.defaults({
  whitelist: "token"
})
```

and

```
Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('token');
```

But none seemed to work. But either method working fine while `cypress open` i.e. GUI mode. Any ideas where I am coming short?

Answer (score 0):

for cypress 12, we can pass option `cacheAcrossSpecs` in the `cy.session` function. Its useful if we have multiple specs file that require session. We can request for the session once.

This is the reference from the cypress docs. [Reference](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session#Caching-session-data-across-specs)

Answer (score 0):

In the new Cypress version 12 or 13, you can easily set `testIsolation: false` in the Cypress configuration file.

```
//-- cypress.config.js --//

const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
  ...
  testIsolation: false,
  ...
  },
})
```

Reference:

- https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/test-isolation#What-is-Test-Isolation
- https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#e2e

Comment: `testIsolation:true` is the default setting (no need to set it). You mean `testIsolation:false` to preserve data across tests.