# Page Object Pattern in Cypress?

Tags: e2e-testing, cypress

I want to use a workflow similar to the Page Object Pattern that exists in frameworks like Selenium. I want to use my `login.spec.js` in my `editSettings.spec.js`, because it requires a user to be logged in.

How do I achieve this in Cypress? Can I export a function from one test file to use in another?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Cypress supports the ability to create and reuse actions in your UI, such as logging in as a user would.

*However*, Cypress also allows you to control the state of the browser **more powerfully** than a user would.

For example: I create a test that a "user can log in with valid username and password"- Cypress navigates to the login page, types in the user field, types in the password field and clicks the "Log in" button. The **Page Object Pattern** would have you reuse this action on *every test that requires a user to be logged in* (most of the tests)

Cypress supports this; however, **this is slower than it has to be**. It takes a considerable amount of time to navigate to a login page, type in the information, handle the response, and navigate to the page under test. 
*Instead*, `Cypress`'s API allows the following:

- use `cy.request()` to directly hit your server with the login credentials. This requires no state of your app, no typing in fields, no clicking buttons, or page directs
- Any cookies your site uses **are automatically set**, or you can [set localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50471047/preserve-cookies-localstorage-session-across-tests-in-cypress) using the response
- Make this a custom command, call it before every test, and boom- you've generated your user's state almost instantly and most importantly flake-free

Answer (score 2):

I actually came up with these two examples, one using JavaScript and another one with Typescript.

https://github.com/antonyfuentes/cypress-typescript-page-objects
https://github.com/antonyfuentes/cypress-javascript-page-objects

Hopefully, this helps someone else.

Answer (score -2):

Create a `SearchProduct.js` file in fixtures folder (You can create it anywhere).Then create a class in it and define your all the methods in it something like this:

```
class ProductPage {
    getSearchClick() {
        return cy.get('.noo-search');
    }
    getSearchTextBox(){
        return cy.get('.form-control');
    }
    getProductsName() {
        return cy.get('.noo-product-inner h3');
    }
    getSelectSize() {
        return cy.get('#pa_size');
    }
    getSelectColor() {
        return cy.get('#pa_color');
    }
    getAddtoCartButton() {
        return cy.get('.single_add_to_cart_button');
    }
    }

export default ProductPage
```

After creating the class, let's import it in the `command.js` file. After that, let's create a new object of it to access all the methods mentioned above in `commands.js`.

```
import ProductPage from '../support/PageObjects/ProductPage';

Cypress.Commands.add("selectProduct", (productName, size , color) => { 
    // Creating Object for ProductPage
    const productPage=new ProductPage();

    // Doing the search part for Shirts.
    productPage.getSearchClick().click()
    productPage.getSearchTextBox().type('Shirt');
    productPage.getSearchTextBox().type('{enter}')
    
    productPage.getProductsName().each(($el , index , $list) => {
        //cy.log($el.text());
        if($el.text().includes(productName)) {
            cy.get($el).click();
        }
    })

    // Selecting the size and color and then adding to cart button. 
    productPage.getSelectColor().select(color);
    productPage.getSelectSize().select(size);
    productPage.getAddtoCartButton().click();
 })
```

So, here actually the custom command's class is importing and using the Page class. Additionally, the test script will use the same `command.js` to perform the needed action.
So, the test script will still be the same and will look as below:

```
// type definitions for Cypress object "cy"
// <reference types="cypress" />
 
describe('Cypress Page Objects and Custom Commands', function() {
    
    //Mostly used for Setup Part
    before(function(){
    cy.fixture('example').then(function(data)
    {
        this.data=data ;
    })
    })
    
    it('Cypress Test Case', function() {
  
    //Registration on the site
    cy.visit('https://shop.demoqa.com/my-account/');
    cy.get('#reg_username').type(this.data.Username);
    cy.get('#reg_email').type(this.data.Email);
    cy.get('#reg_password').type(this.data.NewPassword);
    cy.get('.woocommerce-Button').click();
 
    //Checking whether the Registration is successful and whether UserName is populated under login section
    cy.get('#username').should('have.value',this.data.Username);
    })
 
    // For Loop for Accessing productName array from Features File and Using the custom command
    this.data.productName.forEach(function(element){
        // Invoke the Custom command selectProduct
        cy.selectProduct(element[0],element[1],element[2]);
    })
})
```

**You can also directly import the class in Test File by skipping** `Command.js` **file.**

For that go to the following link:

**Courtesy**: https://softans.com/cypress-page-object-model/